# Codeigniter how to load all js files from folder

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Codeigniter how to load all js files from folder, without mentioning name of file.

Example- I want to get all js file from one folder. I know the path up to folder but js files are created dynamically when build is created so do not know exact name of files to load tradional way.

Comment: Regardless of CodeIgniter, you can't include files when you don't know the file's name.

Comment: @sparky - couldn't you read the directory and then load them?

Comment: @cartalot, technically yes... blindly include every file that happens to be in a directory.  Does not seem very smart.

Comment: @sparky - with respect -  please delete your first response since its not correct.

Comment: Seema this should get you started - try coding something and if it doesn't work post again with the code you tried http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html#get_filenames

Comment: I got the solution. Posted in Answers section. Thanks All!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solution will going to work

```
$js_path = rtrim(FCPATH . 'assets/js', '/'); // FCPATH = root folder of your codeigniter project

$js_files = glob("{" . $js_path . "/*.js}", GLOB_BRACE);

for($i = 0; $i < count($js_files); $i++){
    echo read_file($js_files[$i]);
}
```

code not tested but I hope this will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried following that worked for me

```
        $folderpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/common/js/';
        $fileName = array();
        $fileName = get_filenames($folderpath);
        $jsFiles = array();
        foreach($fileName as $file){
            $url = 'resources/common/js/'.$file;
            $jsFiles[]['js'] = base_url($url);
        }
        $this->load->vars($jsFiles);
```